# Javascript tests break when switching from Selenium to Poltergeist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium-webdriver, capybara, integration-testing, poltergeist

I have a few feature tests that are completely breaking once I switched from Selenium to Poltergeist. The interesting thing is that the breakage occurs with AJAX calls I am making to a third party external API called Mailgun for email validation.

With Selenium, all tests pass. With Poltergeist, the tests behave in the exact opposite manner they are supposed to. In other words, with Poltergeist, all valid emails are being flagged as invalid and vice versa. Other then some Poltergeist syntax, nothing in my tests have changed.

What could possibly be causing Poltergeist to fail JS tests that were passing with Selenium?

Edit to include sample code:

Feature test:

```
scenario "with missing required parameters" do
  visit new_subscriber_path
  fill_in 'subscriber_firstname', with: ''
  fill_in 'subscriber_lastname', with: 'Appleseed'
  fill_in 'subscriber_account_attributes_email', with: 'john@yahoo.com'
  fill_in 'subscriber_account_attributes_password', with: 'test123'
  fill_in 'subscriber_account_attributes_password_confirmation', with: 'test123'
  click_button 'Next'

  page.should have_selector('.error', text: "can't be blank")
  expect(current_path).to eq subscribers_path
end
```

Output: (This test passes without issues with Selenium).

```
1) Subscriber registering with missing required parameters
     Failure/Error: page.should have_selector('.error', text: "can't be blank")
       expected to find css ".error" with text "can't be blank" but there were no matches. Also found "", "", "This doesn't seem like a valid email address.", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", which matched the selector but not all filters.
     # ./spec/features/subscriber_registration_spec.rb:45:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Mailgun validator:

```
$.fn.mailgun_validator = function(options) {
    return this.each(function() {
      run_validator($(this).val(), options);
    });
};

function run_validator(address_text, options) {
    // don't run validator without input
    if (!address_text) {
        return;
    }

    // length check
    if (address_text.length > 512) {
        error_message = 'Stream exceeds maxiumum allowable length of 512.';
        if (options && options.error) {
            options.error(error_message);
        }
        else {
            console.log(error_message);
        }
        return;
    }

    // validator is in progress
    if (options && options.in_progress) {
        options.in_progress();
    }

    // require api key
    if (options && options.api_key == undefined) {
        console.log('Please pass in api_key to mailgun_validator.')
    }

    var success = false;

    // make ajax call to get validation results
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'https://api.mailgun.net/v2/address/validate?callback=?',
        data: { address: address_text, api_key: options.api_key },
        dataType: "jsonp",
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function(data, status_text) {
            success = true;
            if (options && options.success) {
                options.success(data);
            }
        },
        error: function(request, status_text, error) {
            success = true;
            error_message = 'Error occurred, unable to validate address.';

            if (options && options.error) {
                options.error(error_message);
            }
            else {
                console.log(error_message);
            }
        }
    });

    // timeout incase of some kind of internal server error
    setTimeout(function() {
        error_message = 'Error occurred, unable to validate address.';
        if (!success) {
            if (options && options.error) {
                options.error(error_message);
            }
            else {
                console.log(error_message);
            }
        }
    }, 30000);

}
```

Mailgun validator implementation:

```
//= require mailgun_validator/mailgun_validator

var MailgunEmailValidator = function(emailTextField) {
  this.htmlElements = {
    emailField: $(emailTextField),
    form: $(emailTextField.form),
    errorField: $(emailTextField).siblings('.error')
  }
};

MailgunEmailValidator.PublicKey = 'pubkeyfoo';

MailgunEmailValidator.prototype.focusoutValidation = function () {
  var _this = this;
  $(_this.htmlElements.emailField).focusout(function() {
    _this.htmlElements.emailField.mailgun_validator({
      api_key: MailgunEmailValidator.PublicKey,
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data)
        _this.isEmailValid = data.is_valid;
        if (_this.isEmailValid) {
          _this.showSuccess(data.did_you_mean);
        } else {
          _this.showError();
        }
      }
    });
  });
};

MailgunEmailValidator.prototype.prepopulatedFieldValidation = function() {
  var _this = this;
  if(_this.htmlElements.emailField[0].defaultValue) {
    _this.htmlElements.emailField.mailgun_validator({
      api_key: MailgunEmailValidator.PublicKey,
      success: function(data) {
        _this.isEmailValid = data.is_valid;
        if (_this.isEmailValid) {
          _this.showSuccess(data.did_you_mean);
        } else {
          _this.showError();
        }
      }
    });
  }
}

MailgunEmailValidator.prototype.showSuccess = function(didYouMean) {
  var _this = this,
      text = '';
  if(didYouMean) {
    text = '<font color="green">Address is valid. (Though did you mean ' + didYouMean + ')</font>';
  }
  if (_this.htmlElements.errorField.length == 0) {
    _this.htmlElements.errorField = $('<div>', {
      'class': 'error'
    });
  }
  _this.htmlElements.emailField.after(_this.htmlElements.errorField.html(text));
};

MailgunEmailValidator.prototype.showError = function() {
  var _this = this;
  if (_this.htmlElements.errorField.length == 0) {
    _this.htmlElements.errorField = $('<div>', {
      'class': 'error'
    });
  }
  _this.htmlElements.emailField.after(_this.htmlElements.errorField.text("This doesn't seem like a valid email address."));
};

MailgunEmailValidator.prototype.bindPreventInvalidEmailFormSubmissionEvent = function() {
  var _this = this;
  _this.htmlElements.form.on('submit', function(event) {
    if (!_this.isEmailValid) {
      event.preventDefault();
      _this.showError();
      _this.htmlElements.emailField[0].scrollIntoView();
    }
  });
};

MailgunEmailValidator.prototype.bindEvents = function() {
  this.bindPreventInvalidEmailFormSubmissionEvent();
};

MailgunEmailValidator.prototype.init = function() {
  this.focusoutValidation();
  this.prepopulatedFieldValidation();
  this.bindEvents();
};

MailgunEmailValidator.init = function() {
  this.emailFields = $('.mailgun');
  this.emailFields.each(function() {
    new MailgunEmailValidator(this).init();
  });
}
```

The only config I added for poltergeist is the following in spec_helper:

```
Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
```

Comment: You can hardly expect anyone to help when you've not included at least some of your code.  Your question at the moment is far too broad

Comment: I figured this was more a of a theoretical problem with how poltergeist functions with JS. I'm happy to include code, but forewarning, it's pretty standard capybara.

Comment: It's going to be easier to track down than somewhere within capybara or poltergeist or selenium there is a bug.

Comment: No problem. Code included in edit, thanks!

Comment: If you increase the default wait time of capybara will it pass?  I can only think that the ajax hasn't finished running yet.

Comment: I believe the ajax is running, because the "This doesn't seem like a valid email address." is being populated. That error wouldn't be filling if the mailgun script wasn't getting an AJAX response

Comment: Please post your poltergeist config

Comment: Edited into the question. I only had `Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist` in spec_helper

Comment: You're absolutely sure you didn't set up a url blacklist for poltergeist?

Comment: Yes, I am 100% sure about that

Comment: Ok then try taking a screenshot and seeing whats actually filled in

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95065/discussion-between-anthony-to-and-tom-walpole).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mailgun API is over https.  PhantomJS (used by poltergeist) can have some issues with SSL and configuration. If when you create your poltergeist driver you specify the ignore-ssl-errors option for phantomjs then it should work

```
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, phantomjs_options: ['--ignore-ssl-errors=true'])
end
```

You may also want to specify the '--ssl-protocol=TLSv1' option depending on server setup.